# how does tour work in odoo

Tags: odoo-11, bootstrap-tour

I have written a simple views/menu_items.xml to make a basic view of res.patner to test how tour works in odoo

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <act_window id="action_all_customers"
        name="All customers"
        res_model="res.partner"
        view_mode="list,form"
        domain="[('customer', '=', True)]"
        context="{'default_customer': True}"
        limit="80" />
    <menuitem id="menu_custom_toplevel"
        name="My custom menu" />
    <menuitem id="menu_custom_left"
        parent="menu_custom_toplevel"
        name="This will appear in the left bar" />
    <menuitem id="menu_all_customers"
        parent="menu_custom_left"
        action="action_all_customers"
        sequence="10"
        groups="" />
</odoo>
```

and in the project/static/src/js I worte a simple 2 step tour with the name example tour

```
    odoo.define('example.tour',function(require){
        "use strict";

        var core =require('web.core');
        var tour =require('web_tour.tour');

        var _t=core._t;

        tour.register('example_tour',{
            url:"/web",
        },[tour.STEPS.MENU_MORE,{
            trigger:'.oe_menu_toggler[data-menu-xmlid="chap10.menu_custom_toplevel"]',
            content:_t('Want to <b>create customers</b>?<br/><i>Click on My customer menu to start.</i>'),
            position:'bottom',
        },
        {
            trigger: '.o_list_button_add',
            content: _t('Let\'s create your first customer.'),
            position: 'right',
            width: 200,
        }
    ]);

});
```

I have written the asset file as well.
 In odoo when I start my "example.tour" from start tour from the developer tours it works fine and shows me the tour running quickly but how do I make the tour appear automatically when I login it did sometimes appear automatically for other tours and sometimes for my tour but I don't how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is simple delete the cookies on the odoo page this will solve the problem.
and if that dosent work in odoo you have to activate developer mode (with assets) go to settings on the right corner of the page there you will find the option activate developer mode (with assets) press on it and then after that on your left corner of the scree there is the dashboard 
in (General Settings Technical>User interface>Tours) and delete the tours you want to reuse

Answer (score -2):

i was faced this problem yesterday and finally, I found the solution, this slowly guide tour and if you want to the tips appear with the content you need, as natural this process should appear first time and once one time to the new user so you should delete the database and crete new one in this case the automatic tour will appear

Comment: Could you please rephrase that? As it stands it is not easily understandable, it seems lile you wrote your answer in a hurry or something.